# Class from c# assembly not visible to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, interop

I have an assembly which was written in C#.  Inside of it, I have a number of static classes that have static functions etc.  Referencing these functions from another c# project works just fine, but if I try to use them in a VB.NET project, the classes are not available / visible at all, even though they appear in the object browser, and the project will compile / run as long as I don't reference said classes.

Here is how I define the class in C#, for example...

```
namespace Tools
{
    public static class MyTools
    {
        public static int SumNumber(int n1, int n2) { return n1 + n2; }
    }
}
```

Attempting to use the class in VB will result in the error:

```
'MyTools' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

Attempts to use a fully qualified name 'Tools.MyTools.SumNumber....' will result in the exact same error message.

I have checked, both the C# assembly and the VB project are targeting .NET 4.5
What am I missing here?

Comment: What *exactly* happens if you try to use the class? And what namespace is it in?

Comment: I get an error message saying that the name is not declared.  I have updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: Can you come up with a short but complete example (both the C# code and the VB code accessing it)? This really should work fine. You don't have another reference which might have a non-public class of the same name, do you?

Comment: Are you targeting the same architecture (ie Any CPU, x86, x64 etc) on both?

Comment: I second Jon's request for a *complete* example. I just tried to create a VB project referencing a C# library project. In the C# library project, I copied *the exact code* you were using, and I can use it perfectly fine in the VB project.

Comment: Are you referencing your C# project from the VB project? Does the same problem occur with a non-static C# class? Are there any other compilation warnings or errors?

Comment: The given example is as complete as I can possibly get it.  I have an empty console application in VB, referencing an assembly.  I am referencing the correct assembly, the framework versions + target platforms are the same. Nothing in the assembly is 'visible' from code.  There are no compilation errors or warnings.  I also agree that it should work, but seems not to be.

Comment: It's not complete until you post vb code that tries to use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleared the 'Root Namespace' option in the project properties and now everything is working fine.  Leaving it in leads to non-obvious namespace nesting that confuses programmers.

Comment: Hmm, no, it only confused you.  Use Object Browser next time.

Comment: So you aren't going to mark my answer as correct, or even up-vote it?

Comment: Nope, it isn't correct.  "Use the proper namespace" is obvious/vague. The real issue was the root namespace obfuscating the "proper" ones.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is typically due to not using the proper namespace when you try to use the class.  Get the full namespace from the C# code then use that namespace to fully qualify the class name when calling it on the VB side.  If that works you should either import that namespace at the project or file level, or rework your namespaces for easier access.

If that still doesn't work make sure you have a proper reference to the c# project from the VB project.  Make sure you didn't accidentally reference a copy of the output dll or some other stale file.

Comment: Like I said in the question, using the fully qualified namespace doesn't work either.